# Show implicit differentiation is invalid

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

I've got this question
: Given $x^2 + y^2 − 2x + 4y = −9$, find $y'$. (I found $y' = -(x+1)/(y+2)$.

But then, it asks: Show that the result is nonsense. (Hint: appeal to the conditions of the implicit function theorem.)

I don't understand how I can do this. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $x^2 + y^2 - 2x + 4y = (x-1)^2 + (y+2)^2 - 5$. Can this expression become equal to $-9$?

Comment: How can there be a 5? Shouldn't it be 4 then?

Comment: @ArthurRimbaud I'm not sure I understand your question. Expand the right hand side to see what happens. (I completed the squares.)